# Алгоритм поиска ближайшей свободной позиции

Tags: алгоритм, разработка-игр, геометрия

Есть 2d пространство, в котором размещены объекты (круги или квадраты (что проще)) произвольного размера в произвольных позициях. Объекты анимированы - т.е. каждый кадр их позиция по x\y меняется. Задача в том, что если один из объектов пересекается с другим или группой других, то он должен оказаться выше их по оси y, но как можно ближе к исходной позиции y. X-координата при этом должна сохраниться постоянной. Т.е. если объекты столкнулись, то они распределяются в столбец один над другим.

Прототип вопроса тут - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32508204/finding-nearest-free-position-for-an-object-for-any-point-x-y-in-a-2d-space-wi/32520999 - к сожалению ответ найти не удалось.

**Обновление**

Если сразу несколько объектов пришло в одну и ту же позицию, то произвольный объект должен в ней остаться, а остальные оказаться над ним (выше). В следующем кадре (когда и если объекты уже не пересекаются) они занимают свои "родные" позиции. Т.е. идея всего этого дела в том, что объекты никогда не должны наложиться один на другой - они всегда должны быть видимы. А если они за счет внешнего воздействия должны оказаться в одной позиции (либо частично перекрыть друг друга), то тогда они должны распределиться вертикально в столбик, чтобы опять же остаться видимыми

Comment: все объекты с каждым кадром меняют свое расположение или один? Мы знаем как каждый из элементов двигается (в какую сторону)? Направление движения меняется со временем?

Comment: @BogolyubskiyAlexey да, все объекты с каждым кадром меняют свое расположение. Закон движения элементов заранее не известен. Направление движения меняется, безусловно.

Comment: а кто занимает позицию если сраз несколько объектов пришло в одну и ту же позицию?

Comment: http://smartcook.info/testgame/test3.html Что то такое делаешь?

Comment: @korolariya нет, то, что делаю, можно представить (в 2d) как беспорядочно летающие по экрану шарики, к каждому из которых привязана подсказка (hint) на палочке. Размер подсказки значительно больше размера шарика. Подсказки ни в каком случае (даже если шарики находятся очень рядом друг с другом) не должны накладываться друг на друга, равно как не должны накладываться и на сами шарики.

Comment: @Ilya суть в том что алгоритм один и тот же, A*. Вы ищите путь для полета в матрице, то есть свободное место, лучше добавь наглядности вопросу нарисуй картинку. Если обобщить то для движения используется 2 вещи, это вектора и матрицы, ну или в случае с зомбиками совместил оба. Каждый зомбик занимает позицию в матрице, и следующий при прощете пути будет ее обходить, там старый тест я в пример привел, там координаты матрицы перепутаны

Answer (score 1):

Имеет смысл организовать хранение в BSP - дереве. Найдя нужный квадрант, можно уже в нем искать нужную точку.

BSP позволяет быстро (со скоростью экспоненты) искать, кто с кем пересекается. Далее, останется сделать банальный скан снизу вверх, и готово.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.